# Slices in CSS pie chart are offset

Tags: css, pie-chart

I'm trying to create half a pie chart using CSS. It looks pretty good, but something is slightly offset with the slices. As you can see in the [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/twEAK), the previous slices stretch further than the later ones. Why?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slice slice1"></div>
    <div class="slice slice2"></div>
    <div class="slice slice3"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   margin-left: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   clip: rect(0px, 300px, 150px, 0px);
}

.slice {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 300px 300px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.slice1 { 
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
  transform:rotate(0deg);
}
.slice2 { 
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(11deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(11deg);
  transform:rotate(11deg);
}
.slice3 { 
  background-color: yellow;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(73deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(73deg);
  transform:rotate(73deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a CSS pie chart code and just modified it to make it a half circle

*HTML*

```
<div id="piechart">
   <div class="pie" data-start="0" data-value="30"></div>
   <div class="pie highlight" data-start="30" data-value="30"></div>
   <div class="pie" data-start="60" data-value="40"></div>
   <div class="pie big" data-start="100" data-value="260"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#piechart {
  position:absolute;
  clip:rect(0px, 251px, 100px, 0px);
}

/* 
  make each pie piece a rectangle twice as high as it is wide.
  move the transform origin to the middle of the left side.
  Also ensure that overflow is set to hidden.
*/
  .pie {
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:200px;
        overflow:hidden;
        left:150px;
        -moz-transform-origin:left center;
        -ms-transform-origin:left center;
        -o-transform-origin:left center;
        -webkit-transform-origin:left center;
        transform-origin:left center;
    }
/*
  unless the piece represents more than 50% of the whole chart.
  then make it a square, and ensure the transform origin is
  back in the center.

  NOTE: since this is only ever a single piece, you could
  move this to a piece specific rule and remove the extra class
*/
    .pie.big {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        left:50px;
        -moz-transform-origin:center center;
        -ms-transform-origin:center center;
        -o-transform-origin:center center;
        -webkit-transform-origin:center center;
        transform-origin:center center;
    }
/*
  this is the actual visible part of the pie. 
  Give it the same dimensions as the regular piece.
  Use border radius make it a half circle.
  move transform origin to the middle of the right side.
  Push it out to the left of the containing box.
*/
    .pie:BEFORE {
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:200px;
        left:-100px;
        border-radius:100px 0 0 100px;
        -moz-transform-origin:right center;
        -ms-transform-origin:right center;
        -o-transform-origin:right center;
        -webkit-transform-origin:right center;
        transform-origin:right center;

    }
 /* if it's part of a big piece, bring it back into the square */
    .pie.big:BEFORE {
        left:0px;
    }
/* 
  big pieces will also need a second semicircle, pointed in the
  opposite direction to hide the first part behind.
*/
    .pie.big:AFTER {
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:200px;
        left:100px;
        border-radius:0 100px 100px 0;
    }
/*
  add colour to each piece.
*/
    .pie:nth-of-type(1):BEFORE,
    .pie:nth-of-type(1):AFTER {
        background-color:blue;  
    }
    .pie:nth-of-type(2):AFTER,
    .pie:nth-of-type(2):BEFORE {
        background-color:green; 
    }
    .pie:nth-of-type(3):AFTER,
    .pie:nth-of-type(3):BEFORE {
        background-color:red;   
    }
    .pie:nth-of-type(4):AFTER,
    .pie:nth-of-type(4):BEFORE {
        background-color:orange;    
    }
/*
  now rotate each piece based on their cumulative starting
  position
*/
    .pie[data-start="30"] {
        -moz-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
        transform:rotate(30deg);
    }
    .pie[data-start="60"] {
        -moz-transform: rotate(60deg); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: rotate(60deg); /* IE */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: rotate(60deg); /* Opera */
        transform:rotate(60deg);
    }
    .pie[data-start="100"] {
        -moz-transform: rotate(100deg); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: rotate(100deg); /* IE */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: rotate(100deg); /* Opera */
        transform:rotate(100deg);
    }
/*
  and rotate the amount of the pie that's showing.

  NOTE: add an extra degree to all but the final piece, 
  to fill in unsightly gaps.
*/
    .pie[data-value="30"]:BEFORE {
        -moz-transform: rotate(31deg); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: rotate(31deg); /* IE */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(31deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: rotate(31deg); /* Opera */
        transform:rotate(31deg);
    }
    .pie[data-value="40"]:BEFORE {
        -moz-transform: rotate(41deg); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: rotate(41deg); /* IE */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(41deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: rotate(41deg); /* Opera */
        transform:rotate(41deg);
    }
    .pie[data-value="260"]:BEFORE {
        -moz-transform: rotate(260deg); /* Firefox */
        -ms-transform: rotate(260deg); /* IE */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(260deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
        -o-transform: rotate(260deg); /* Opera */
        transform:rotate(260deg);
    }
/*
NOTE: you could also apply custom classes (i.e. .s0 .v30)
but if the CSS3 attr() function proposal ever gets implemented,
then all the above custom piece rules could be replaced with
the following:

.pie[data-start] {
   transform:rotate(attr(data-start,deg,0);
}
.pie[data-value]:BEFORE {
   transform:rotate(attr(data-value,deg,0);
}
*/
```

The pie chart code is from http://codepen.io/AtomicNoggin/pen/fEish

Comment: Thanks, but I'm curious about the effect in my example.

Comment: Which effect are you curious about?

Comment: The slices not matching up pixel perfectly. You can see the effect in the Codepen example I provided.

Comment: Are you talking about on your yellow slice how you see the green and red pixels at the edge?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to grab the existing pie chart code I posted above and use that? Simply change the data-start and data-value values in the html and the size of the pie chart itself. It would save you a lot of headache in the end

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to. And, yes, I could do that but then I won't learn what's wrong with my original example :)

Comment: Ok I understand, I will take a look at it again and see what I can find

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out why there is a gap there. Play around with the BEFORE and AFTER like in the code I pasted above and see if you can figure something out. I apologize, but I have no answer for that. My guess is it has to do with the radius/rounding of the corner section of the div/rectangle/square and where it meets the straight section and that the gap you see is result of the rounded section straightening out.

Comment: There is another option that you can use for this though. It removes 99% of the gap and uses pretty much the same existing code that you have. If you add this to container:
  border-radius:300px 300px 300px 300px;
  overflow:hidden;
and remove the border-radius from .slice you'll see less of the existing gap